# codeigniter, select twice or not

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm wondering if i would need to select (where statement) twice, if i wanted tp update a spesific user in the database.

Example,

```
// Add new income for the day
function add_new_income($user_id, $budget_group_id, $day, $month, $year, $income)
{

    // Check if there has been posted anything at the same day
    $this->db->where('day',$this->current_date);
    $this->db->where('month',$this->current_month);
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $this->db->where('budget_group_id',$budget_group_id);

    $query = $this->db->get('budget_day',1);

    // Check if something was found
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        // If something was found, update the value
        $data = array('income_total' => $income);
        $this->db->update('budget_day',$data);
    }

}
```

Would this work? Or do i have to run a new "db->where" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write where condition twice, but you can try it in single line as follows:

```
$this->db->where(array('day'=>$this->current_date, 'month'=>$this->current_month, 'user_id'=>$user_id, 'budget_group_id'=>$budget_group_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write new `where` conditions for `update`. Better would be to store all the `where` conditions in `array` and use that `array` for `select` and `update` if you must.

```
$where = array(
    'day' => $this->current_date,
    'month' => $this->current_month,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'budget_group_id' => $budget_group_id
);
...
$this->db->where($where);
```

In your case it seems no need of two quires, you just need to run `update` query. You can use `$this->db->affected_rows()` to check if something was updated.